# Cordova PDFkit blob-stream to IPP Printer?

Tags: javascript, cordova, printing, blob, node-pdfkit

I'm using the browser version of [PDFkit](http://pdfkit.org) within Cordova to generate a pdf. Is it possible to send this pdf stream to an IPP printer (eg. http://printserver.local:631/printer1)? Perhaps using an http plugin like [cordovaHTTP](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP)?

Comment: As far as I know, you'd need to send a PS stream to the printer. To go from PDF to PS within cordova you'd need to implement something like https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer

Answer (score 1):

An http plugin won't help much. You need to use a proper IPP protocol implementation.

Answer: By using a thirdparty IPP implementation you can send/print pdf.

(Assumption: Cordova-Apps do not suffer from CORS or other network-limitations)